# How to pass id in path url as component property in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm updating an outdated tutorial project using react hooks and react router v6. I want to pass the id in the path url to the component property..

```
function App() {
  const findPalette = (id) => {
    return colorsData.find((palette) => palette.id === id);
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<h1>Palette List goes here!</h1>} />
      <Route path="/palette/:id" element={<Palette palette={generatePalette(findPalette(requiredID))} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

What should I do in place of 'requiredID' to get it done?

Here is the code in the tutorial

```
<Route 
  exact 
  path='/palette/:id' 
  render={routeProps => <Palette palette={generatePalette(this.findPalette(routeProps.match.params.id))} />} 
/>
```

I found useParams() in the documentation, but it is used inside the function component passed to the element property

```
function ProfilePage() {
  // Get the userId param from the URL.
  let { userId } = useParams();
  // ...
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="users">
        <Route path=":userId" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path="me" element={...} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom hook that wraps `useParams`:

```
const usePalette = () => {
  const { userId: id } = useParams();

  return useMemo(() => colorsData.find(palette => palette.id === id), []);
}

function ProfilePage() {
  const palette = usePalette();
  // ...
}
```

If you can't change `ProfilePage` create a wrapper component (`ProfilePageWrapper`) that uses the hook, and let it render `ProfilePage`.

```
const ProfilePageWrapper () => {
  const palette = usePalette();
  
  return <ProfilePage palette={palette} />;
}
```

Then use the wrapper in the route:

```
<Route path="/palette/:id" element={<ProfilePageWrapper />} />
```